# Flask returning posted JSON back

Tags: python, json, flask

I have my Flask routes defined like so:

```
# main.py
from flask import Blueprint, request

main = Blueprint('main',__name__)
@main.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@main.route("/keke/")
def keke():
    return "Hello Keke!"

@main.route("/upload/", methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if request.json:
        return request.json
```

The `upload` route receives a JSON that is posted. I would like to return that JSON back so I can check that the contents arrived at the server OK. However the line `return request.json` throws the error `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.json` is the *decoded Python object*. Use the [`jsonify()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.json.jsonify) to turn that back into a JSON response:

```
from flask import jsonify

@main.route("/upload/", methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    if request.json:
        return jsonify(request.json)
```